# AccessViolationException when calling function put_ClassName

Tags: .net, com, c++-cli, ui-automation

I am trying to use a predefined function but keep getting an AccessViolationException. I am using com objects as well. I call the function put_ClassName(BSTR obj) but keep getting an exception.

This is probably a silly error but here is a sample:

```
IUIAutomationProxyFactory* factory;
IUIAutomationProxyFactoryEntry* entry;
IUIAutomationProxyFactoryMapping* pMap;
LPCWSTR className = L"CustomUIAutomationCPP";
BSTR name;

CoInitialize(NULL);
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomation, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IUIAutomation, (void**)&pAutomation);
(*pAutomation).get_ProxyFactoryMapping(&pMap);
factory = new CustomProxyFactory();
(*pAutomation).CreateProxyFactoryEntry(factory, &entry);

name = SysAllocString(className);
(*entry).put_ClassName(className);
```

I have no clue why I am getting this error. Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

It seems I am not getting the mapping to the proxy table with the above call to:

```
(*pAutomation).get_ProxyFactoryMapping(&pMap);
```

Can anyone tell me if there is another way to get the table mapping??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't assinged anything to entry, right now it's just an uninitialised pointer.

Comment: I have edited the code above to show how I get to that point. I believe CreateProxyFactoryEntry(...) instantiates the variable.

Comment: Have you checked in debugger/via log that it's really assigned? And can you show the code of CreateProxyFactoryEntry?

Comment: I have checked the debugger and entry seems to be assigned to a com object (IUnknown). That function is from IUIAutomationProxyFactory::CreateProxyFactoryEntry

Comment: Yes, that's the one I'm using... :)  Any clues? I have tried className and name :(

Comment: According to MDSN put_ClassName requires and not BSTR HRESULT put_ClassName( LPCWSTR className ); Try calling (*entry).put_ClassName(className);

Comment: Don't see any other potential problem here, check CustomProxyFactory code

Comment: I looked again and it seems that I am not getting the mapping to the proxy table.

Comment: What HRESULT do you get? And post better bigger chunk of your code.

Comment: hr = E_INVALIDARG = -2147024809, above I have added my interface and provider. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise sp1 32-bit. I do have the updated version of microsoft's Automation API as well.

Comment: If you get E_INVALIDARG from ProxyFactoryMapping - the problem is not in your provider, it wasn't created by that moment. Have you called ComInitialize? And how exactly do you create pAutomation?

Comment: I use CoInitialize(NULL); and CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomationRegistrar, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IUIAutomationRegistrar, (void**)&pAutomation); to get everything started. Sorry, I guess I missed that in the code above.

Comment: One last thing - try changing CLSCTX_ALL to CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, all examples I see on the WEB create your interface inproc. Don't see what else can be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your help! My mistake was the clsid in that function!! I knew it was a silly mistake...lol

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, there was a silly mistake with the clsid that I was using and now I am able to make an entry in the proxy table.

At this point, I am wondering when I am suppose to be instantiating my server-side provider and my client-side provider. Also, whether or not they should exist for the lifetime of the program since I would like to catch events from my custom pattern. One more thing, how to add my custom pattern to automation elements so the elements can throw my events from my custom pattern.